# How to extract part of a string between two characters from the end?

Tags: r, regex, string, loops

I have multiple columns in a dataframe `df_1` with the same name, ending with ascending numbers in the format of  `Team_URL_1, Team_URL_2, ...` up to 70. These columns contain LinkedIn links in the format of `https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexyz/` from which I want to extract the ID, so the last part *namexyz* between the / /. How can I extract this ID over all columns? An example `dput` looks like this (but keep in mind I need to loop this to account for over 70 of the `Team_URL_n` columns):

```
structure(list(Company = c("csd", "fwef", "wrev"), Team_1 = c("0", 
"werg", "sdf"), Team_Desc_1 = c("wer", "wtrb", "wergt"), Team_URL_1 = c("https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexyz/", 
"https://www.linkedin.com/in/namesrvf/", "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameawrf/"
), Team_Ver_1 = c("25", "2523", "342"), Team_Num_1 = c(0, 23, 
12), Team_Value_1 = c("aed", "jfsa", "vsf"), Team_2 = c("werh", 
"wtt", "qwe"), Team_Desc_2 = c("sdfg", "wer", "sdfgv"), Team_URL_2 = c("https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexqwrg/", 
"https://www.linkedin.com/in/namewqrg/", "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameqerwg/"
), Team_Ver_2 = c("4123", "5133", "4126"), Team_Num_2 = c(3, 
0, 123), Team_Value_2 = c("aewed", "jfsbwa", "vsbf")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

The output should be a new column called `ID_n` (with the respective value at the end) and contain the ID. It should look like this:

```
Company Team_1 Team_Desc_1  Team_URL_1                             Team_Ver_1 Team_Num_1 Team_Value_1 Team_ID_1     ...
csd     0      wer          https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexyz/   25         0          aed          namexyz
fwef    werg   wtrb         https://www.linkedin.com/in/namesrvf/  2523       23         jfsa         namesrvf
wrev    sdf    wergt        https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameawrf/  342        12         vsf          nameawrf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions given above are amazing, although your problem seems to be arrangement. Here are two solutions to tackle that:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Company, names_to = c('.value', 'name'), names_pattern = "(.*)_(\\d+)") %>%
  mutate(Team_ID = basename(Team_URL), .after = Team_Value)%>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Company, values_from = starts_with('Team'), names_vary = 'slowest')

df %>%
  mutate(across(contains('URL'), basename, .names = '{sub("URL", "ID",.col)}'))%>%
  select(1, str_order(sub("\\D+_", "", names(.))))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In base R, You could use `lapply` and `gsub` to extract the desired string, as well as indexing with `paste0` to create new columns named "Team_ID_1", "Team_ID_2", etc:

```
df[paste0("Team_ID_", seq_along(grep("URL", names(df))))] <- lapply(df[grep("URL", names(df))], 
      function(x) gsub(".*[\\/]([^.]+)[\\/].*", "\\1", x))
```

Output:

```
#   Company Team_1 Team_Desc_1                            Team_URL_1 Team_Ver_1 Team_Num_1 Team_Value_1 Team_2 Team_Desc_2                             Team_URL_2 Team_Ver_2 Team_Num_2
# 1     csd      0         wer  https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexyz/         25          0          aed   werh        sdfg https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexqwrg/       4123          3
# 2    fwef   werg        wtrb https://www.linkedin.com/in/namesrvf/       2523         23         jfsa    wtt         wer  https://www.linkedin.com/in/namewqrg/       5133          0
# 3    wrev    sdf       wergt https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameawrf/        342         12          vsf    qwe       sdfgv https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameqerwg/       4126        123

#   Team_Value_2 Team_ID_1 Team_ID_2
# 1        aewed   namexyz namexqwrg
# 2       jfsbwa  namesrvf  namewqrg
# 3         vsbf  nameawrf nameqerwg
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`'s `across`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("Team_URL"),
                ~ gsub("(https:\\/\\/www\\.linkedin\\.com\\/in\\/)(.*)(\\/)", "\\2", .),
                .names = "{sub('URL', 'ID', col)}"
                )
         )
```

Output:

```
  Company Team_1 Team_Desc_1                            Team_URL_1 Team_Ver_1 Team_Num_1 Team_Value_1 Team_2 Team_Desc_2
1     csd      0         wer  https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexyz/         25          0          aed   werh        sdfg
2    fwef   werg        wtrb https://www.linkedin.com/in/namesrvf/       2523         23         jfsa    wtt         wer
3    wrev    sdf       wergt https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameawrf/        342         12          vsf    qwe       sdfgv
                              Team_URL_2 Team_Ver_2 Team_Num_2 Team_Value_2 Team_ID_1 Team_ID_2
1 https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexqwrg/       4123          3        aewed   namexyz namexqwrg
2  https://www.linkedin.com/in/namewqrg/       5133          0       jfsbwa  namesrvf  namewqrg
3 https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameqerwg/       4126        123         vsbf  nameawrf nameqerwg
```

---

Update, to get the sorting as described in the comment below:

Using `str_order` from `stringr` as @onyambu.

```
df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("Team_URL"),
                ~ gsub("(https:\\/\\/www\\.linkedin\\.com\\/in\\/)(.*)(\\/)", "\\2", .),
                .names = "{sub('URL', 'ID', col)}"
                )
         ) %>%
  select(Company, str_order(sub("\\D+_", "", names(.))))
```

Output:

```r
  Company Team_1 Team_Desc_1                            Team_URL_1 Team_Ver_1 Team_Num_1 Team_Value_1 Team_ID_1 Team_2 Team_Desc_2
1     csd      0         wer  https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexyz/         25          0          aed   namexyz   werh        sdfg
2    fwef   werg        wtrb https://www.linkedin.com/in/namesrvf/       2523         23         jfsa  namesrvf    wtt         wer
3    wrev    sdf       wergt https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameawrf/        342         12          vsf  nameawrf    qwe       sdfgv
                              Team_URL_2 Team_Ver_2 Team_Num_2 Team_Value_2 Team_ID_2
1 https://www.linkedin.com/in/namexqwrg/       4123          3        aewed namexqwrg
2  https://www.linkedin.com/in/namewqrg/       5133          0       jfsbwa  namewqrg
3 https://www.linkedin.com/in/nameqerwg/       4126        123         vsbf nameqerwg
``
```